# filepond receive undefined value in hidden input

Tags: javascript, laravel, filepond

receive undefined value in hidden input

```
return Response::make($this->filepond->getServerIdFromPath($filePath), 200, [
            'Content-Type' => 'text/plain',
        ]);
```

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache, private
Content-Type:  text/plain
Date:          Mon, 25 May 2020 11:01:01 GMT

eyJpdiI6Ik1wWEY0UmNSNlRJR.....==
```

response generated correct but  in filepond hidden receive undefined

```
<input type="hidden" name="filepond" value="undefined">
```

this is my server setting

```
FilePond.setOptions({
    server: {
        url: 'http://localhost/gadmin/public/filepond/api',
        timeout: 7000,
        process: {
            url: '/process',
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            },
            onload: (response) => response.key,
            onerror: (response) => response.data,
            ondata: (formData) => {
                return formData;
            }
        },
    }
});
```

Comment: can you add the js code where you update the hidden field after getting the response

Comment: I think this deep in filepond.js

Comment: thx resolve, just delete  ``onload: (response) => response.key `` in server option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `onload` function is only needed if for example your server returns a JSON string and you need to select a certain property from it. In your situation the `process` end point returns a `text/plain` response with an `id`, this allows FilePond to automatically use the returned id as the file id. So that's why the `onload` function isn't needed.

See: https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/patterns/api/server/#process

> server returns unique location id 12345 in text/plain response